# Problems installing MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MySQL 8.0 in Ubuntu 20.04 with `sudo apt install mysql-server`, but this error keeps showing up after reinstalling and after using `sudo dpkg --configure -a` :

```
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/
configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned
 error exit status 127
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I completely uninstalled MySQL and reinstalled it multiple times with `sudo apt remove --purge --autoremove mysql-server`, but the error persists.

Answer (score 28):

I got the same problem and just found nice [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/completely-uninstall-mysql-server)
to solve it.

Indeed deleting files directly from your MySQL folder is really not recommended. You can take a look at this guide here on how to delete old MySQL binary files [here](https://bobbyiliev.com/blog/mysql-how-to-delete-old-binary-logs).

Regarding your current issue. In order to completely get rid of your MySQL installation you could run the following:

1. Make sure MySQL is not running:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl stop mysql
   ```
2. Then purge all the MySQL packages:

   ```bash
   sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
   ```
3. Then delete all the MySQL files:

   ```bash
   sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
   ```
4. Finally clean all packages that are not needed:

   ```bash
   sudo apt autoremove
   sudo apt autoclean
   ```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That worked on Kubuntu jammy 22.04 LTS
 right now.

Comment: It worked perfectly on Ubuntu Server 22.10, maybe should be chosen as the correct answer!!!!

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem trying to install mysql-server on a standard Digital Ocean droplet.  The problem turned out to be that by default the droplet doesn't have enough memory to run mysql-8.0.  There are probably other ways to solve it but I did it by adding a swap partition.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=2048
```

(creates a 2G swapfile, use a different count for different size)

```
chmod 600 /swapfile
mkswap /swapfile
```

Edit /etc/fstab:  and add

```
/swapfile       none    swap    sw       0 0
```

(save and exit)

```
swapon /swapfile
swapon -s # make sure it works
```

Then reinstall mysql-server

Comment: You are the good.. I had the same issue with DO cheapest droplet.. You helped me a lot.. Thank dude

Comment: Fixed it for me - same problem with fresh AWS EC2 nano instance!

Comment: Oh my GOODNESS. I don't even want to think about how much time I would have spent chasing this if I didn't find this.

Answer (score 4):

Stop the Mysql if it is running

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql.service
sudo kill $(pgrep mysql)
```

Then purge everything , this will also remove **Mysql-workbench**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-\*
```

Then reinstall mysql-server and mysql-client

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Comment: Thanks man, This worked for me on ubuntu 20.04